# Postgres "Select Into" runs faster than basic "Select from"

Tags: sql, postgresql

Having trouble with returning the results of large multi million row tables in postgres (pgadmin). Can take up to 30 minutes to get the results back but when i run "Select * into ... from 'Large table'" the process finishes under a minute. Can somebody explain the reason for this?

Comment: pgAdmin is known to be slow when it has to display a large amount of data. But why do you want to _display_ millions of rows anyway? Are you going to read them all?

Answer (score 6):

`SELECT INTO` does not return data to the client, whereas your first `SELECT *` query returns the millions of rows to the pgAdmin client. SELECT * computes on the server-side and does not have to return data to you and so is faster than reading the data on the client.
Reference: [Postgres Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html)

> SELECT INTO creates a new table and fills it with data computed by a query. The data is not returned to the client, as it is with a normal SELECT.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Is the process of reading the data on the client so slow that it explains the 30min vs 1 min query execution time?

Comment: You are not reading the data in batches, are you? pgAdmin will need to execute a select on the server, _wait_ until _all_ millions of rows are returned to the client, and then proceed to render the data in the browser. Multiple steps - 1. select rows on server 2. return rows to browser over the network 3. client-side rendering. No wonder it takes time.

Comment: You can probably track the latency to an extent in your browser's network calls and observe the times taken to get data from the server and for the UI to render.